# redux state inside useLayoutEffect issn't updated after changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I want to fetch a message from Firestore using snapshot, but I need to limit it to 5 messages per fetch

I tried to combine my fetched message with the previous message saved on redux state (chatMessage) to display all the messages sent, the redux state is updated (my displayed chat is using flatlist with redux state as its value) but the redux state on my useLayoutEffect is still using its initial state and even if it updated it wont get updated if the chatMessage is updated from other function (fetchOldMessage)

filterMessage always showing empty array despite chatMessage is updated

```js
const chatId = useSelector((state) => state.local.csChatId);
const chatMessage = useSelector((state) => state.local.csChatMessage);
const messages = collection(database, "messages");

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!chatId) {
      // Dev Only use this chatId 556827be-9a15-495c-80ad-0d53c66ab465
      return () => {dispatch(setChatId("556827be-9a15-495c-80ad-0d53c66ab465"))};
    }

    //Sub messsage
    const qMessage = query(
      messages,
      where("chatId", "==", chatId),
      orderBy("_createdDate", "desc"),
      limit(5)
    );

    const watchMessage = onSnapshot(qMessage, (snapshot) => {
      let itemMsg = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        try {
          const target = {
            ...(doc?.data() || {}),
            _id: doc.id,
            _createdDate: new Date(
              doc.data()._createdDate.seconds * 1000 +
                doc.data()._createdDate.nanoseconds / 1000000
            ).toISOString(),
            _updatedDate: doc.data()._updatedDate
              ? new Date(
                  doc.data()._updatedDate.seconds * 1000 +
                    doc.data()._updatedDate.nanoseconds / 1000000
                ).toISOString()
              : null,
          };
          itemMsg.push(target);
        } catch (error) {
          // empty-line
        }
      });

      // Filter message from redux state
      let filterMessage = chatMessage?.filter(
        (message) => !itemMsg?.find((target) => target?._id == message?._id)
      )

      // Combine old and new message
      let svChatMessage = [...(filterMessage || []), ...(itemMsg || [])]?.sort(
        (a, b) =>
          new Date(b._createdDate).getTime() -
          new Date(a._createdDate).getTime()
      );
      
      // Save message to redux
      dispatch(setChatMessage(svChatMessage));
    });
    return () => watchMessage()
  }, [chatId]);

const fetchOldMessage = async () => {
    let itemMsg = [];

    let qMessage = query(
          messages,
          where("chatId", "==", chatId),
          where(
            "_createdDate",
            "not-in",
            chatMessage?.map((msg) =>
              Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(msg?._createdDate))
            )
          ),
          orderBy("_createdDate", "desc"),
          limit(5)
        );

    const fetchMessage = await getDocs(qMessage);

    if (!fetchMessage?.empty) {
      fetchMessage.forEach((doc) => {
        try {
          const target = {
            ...(doc?.data() || {}),
            _id: doc.id,
            userId: doc.data().userId,
            content: doc.data().content,
            _createdDate: new Date(
              doc.data()._createdDate.seconds * 1000 +
                doc.data()._createdDate.nanoseconds / 1000000
            ).toISOString(),
            _updatedDate: doc.data()._updatedDate
              ? new Date(
                  doc.data()._updatedDate.seconds * 1000 +
                    doc.data()._updatedDate.nanoseconds / 1000000
                ).toISOString()
              : null,
          };
          itemMsg.push(target);
        } catch (error) {
          // empty-line
        }
      });

      // Filter message from redux state
      let filterMessage = chatMessage?.filter(
        (message) => !itemMsg?.find((target) => target?._id == message?._id)
      )

      // Combine old and new message
      let svChatMessage = [...(filterMessage || []), ...(itemMsg || [])]?.sort(
        (a, b) =>
          new Date(b._createdDate).getTime() -
          new Date(a._createdDate).getTime()
      );

      // Save message to redux
      dispatch(setChatMessage(svChatMessage));
    }
  };

const onSend = async () => {
    if (message.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const msg = await createMsg({
      chatId: chatId,
      content: message,
    });
    if (!chatId) {
      dispatch(setChatId(msg.chatId));
    }

    setMessage("");
  };
```

createMessage func

```
export const createMsg = async (data) => {
  const userId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userId");
  const userNickname = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("nickname");

  let chatId;

  if (!data.chatId) {
    const title = `CS ${userNickname}`;
    const chat = await createChat({
      createdById: userId,
      receiverIds: [userId],
      title: title,
    });
    chatId = chat.chatId;
  }

  const messageId = uuid.v4();
  const msg = {
    chatId: data.chatId ? data.chatId : chatId,
    userId: userId,
    readerIds: [userId],
    content: useEncrypt(data?.content),
    _createdDate: new Date(),
    _updatedDate: null,
  };

  await setDoc(doc(database, "messages", messageId), msg);
  // todo: update chat
  await updateDoc(doc(database, "chats", data?.chatId || chatId), {
    length: increment(1),
    _updatedDate: new Date(),
  });

  return {
    messageId: messageId,
    ...msg,
  };
};
```

createChat func

```
export const createChat = async (data) => {
  const chatId = data?.chatId || uuid.v4();
  const body = {
    createdById: data?.createdById || null,
    receiverIds: data?.receiverIds?.length > 0 ? data?.receiverIds : null,
    title: data?.title || null,
    _createdDate: new Date(),
    _updatedDate: null,
  };

  await setDoc(doc(database, "chats", chatId), body);

  return {
    chatId: chatId,
    ...body,
  };
};
```

And this is the flatlist that render the chat

```
<FlatList
    inverted
    data={chatMessage}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 16 }}
    ListFooterComponent={
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.btnFetchMessage}
              onPress={() => fetchOldMessage()}
            >
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Load more message</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        }
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <MessageBubble
            key={index}
            timestamp={item._createdDate}
            isUser={item.userId === user._id}
            message={useDecrypt(item.content).slice(1, -1)}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Comment: The above effect will only run if `chatId` changes.  Does it?  You should provide enough code for people who want to help to reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay I'll try to update my question, and the code above still runs even when there are no changes on dependency (chatId) as long as there are changes on the collection it listens to

Comment: "the code above still runs even when there are no changes on dependency (chatId) as long as there are changes on the collection it listens to" then the collection should be part of your dependency array.  This is an example of something that's not clear without additional code, so be sure to include that in your question:  https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think what @MattMorgan said in the comments is accurate, the useLayoutEffect is not running again due to the `chatId` not changing.

I think it initally runs only because of this at the beginning.

```js
if (!chatId) {
  // Dev Only use this chatId 556827be-9a15-495c-80ad-0d53c66ab465
  return () => {dispatch(setChatId("556827be-9a15-495c-80ad-0d53c66ab465"))};
}
```

And that all effects run twice in dev so the return of this  and also

```js
return () => watchMessage()
```

would run at least once.